# function works from command line but not from within script

Tags: macos, bash, script

I've got a shell script file that launches a ruby dev server and sets the title of the window. For some reason it's not working in OS X but it worked in Ubuntu.

Here's my script:

```
[10:24:48] [user@mac site_web]$ tail ./sdev.sh
#!/bin/bash
title "dev server port 3000"
RAILS_ENV=development rails s -p 3000 --debugger
```

Runs fine from the command line, but fails from within the script.

```
[10:18:17] [user@mac site_web]$ title "dev server" 
title changed
[10:18:29] [user@mac site_web]$ ./sdev.sh
./sdev.sh: line 2: title: command not found
```

That last line is the issue.

And my title function (in my ~/.bash_profile):

```
# function for setting terminal titles in OSX
function title {
  printf "\033]0;%s\007" "$1"
  echo "title changed" 
}
```

Do I need to do this differently because it's on OSX?

Edit: I tried adding the title function to /Users/[me]/.bashrc and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Try putting the function in your `.bashrc` instead

Comment: @slhck as i understand it, that doesn't exist on mac os x

Comment: @slhck looks like that was incorrect; added the function to .bashrc and I'm still getting the error

Comment: Well, it doesn't exist per default but it is read by bash when it is invoked. See http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html — in your case though, you should probably `source ~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.bashrc`) from  your script. I believe there's something I'm missing here, but sourcing the configuration file should make the function available.

Comment: @slhck I tried that just a couple minutes before you commented `if [ -f ~/.bashrc] etc..`, it didn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Mac available to try this, but what if you included a reference to the function source in your script ala:

```
#!/bin/bash
. $HOME/.bash_profile
title "dev server port 3000"
RAILS_ENV=development rails s -p 3000 --debugger
```

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=664657

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. But I added the title function to my ~/.bashrc and the title function was still not available before I tried your fix. Is there a bashrc file elsewhere in the system on a mac?